# How do I call a function which returns a variable, multiple times, while inside another function?

Tags: python, function, return, user-input

I have a function (text-based game) that asks for input multiple times throughout itself, from which all whitespace I would like removed immediately after before proceeding to error checking.

To reduce redundancy, I thought of making another function to do both, and then return the variable like so:

```
def startGame():
    print("1, 2 or 3?")
    response = response()

def response():
    a = raw_input()
    a = a.strip()
    return a

startGame()
```

The problem is I keep getting:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment.

This makes no sense to me since response is assigned `response()`'s return value.
What am I missing? Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You named the local variable `response` **too**; you cannot do that, it masks the global `response()` function.

Rename the local variable, or the function:

```
def get_response():
    # ...


response = get_response()
```

or

```
def response():
    # ....

received_response = response()
```

Comment: @Martijn_Pieters Thanks. I didn't know Python did that, but now I do!

Comment: @JosephWebber: In functions, all names you directly assign to (`somename = ...`) become local variables (the language compiler does this). That does not apply to attributes (`somename.someattribute = `), only to direct names. Thus `response` is already defined as a local name, but you tried to use it before assigning any value to it. That then raises an exception.